# Getting error "property 'style' of undefined" when delete a full column of datatable dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, datatable

This is my html code for table.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered   dt-responsive nowrap" id="log-details">
      <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>User Name</th>
             <th>Status</th>
             <th>Date</th>
             <th>time</th>
             <th>TaskName</th>
             <th>Location</th>

         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
       </tbody>
  </table>
```

This my javascript Code:

```
function dataTableManipulate(mainArray){
        table =  $("#log-details").DataTable({
            data: mainArray,
            "searching": true,
            "info": false,
            "lengthChange":false,
           "columnDefs": [{
               "targets": [5],
                render : function (data, type, row) {
                       return '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs " id = "btnShow">Show Map</button>';
                }
           }]
        });
        $('#tbl_details_length').after($('.datepic-top'));
    }

$("#activitylog").click(function(){
    tableData = generalMainArray
    $('#log-details').dataTable().fnDestroy();
    $('table tr').find('td:eq(4),th:eq(4)').remove();
    dataTableManipulate(tableData);
});
```

**Note:** activitylog is a button.

I want to remove TaskName column from Datatable on  activitylog button click.Any one help me for delete that column from datatable

Comment: can't see where your code is accessing a property called `style` ... that's where the problem occurs, so that's the code you need to post

Comment: @JaromandaX , This error is getting when i add this  line of code  "$('table tr').find('td:eq(4),th:eq(4)').remove();"  into my code

Comment: interesting ... there's no mention of `style` in your code - does the stack trace on the error lead you to that line or some other line in your code?